# Using an iPhone or iPad, how can I access a folder created by FileManager.default.createDirectory(...)?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I've created an iOS app that creates a "Photos" folder using `FileManager`, like this:

```
 let appPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
 let photosPath = appPath.appendingPathComponent("Photos", isDirectory: true)
 try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: photosPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
```

I know I can access that directory in the simulator by using Finder and going to:

```
Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Devices/[my device GUID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[my app GUID]/Documents/Photos
```

But how can I access that folder using the real device itself? (iPad or iPhone)

The native browser doesn't show my app directory

Comment: With Xcode, you can bring up the "Devices & Simulators" window, select the app, and then "Download Container..." using the gear icon below the apps list.

Comment: In my question i said: "using the real device itself". I only have a device and the app installed on it. No xcode. No laptop.

Comment: I didn't see the word "only", sorry.  :)  Since you were talking about Finder and Swift code, I assumed....